# Sending multiple transactions at once?

Tags: transactions

Do you know how Xenon smart contract accomplished sending token to multiple ETH addresses at once like in this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb017eadfd9732efc93238ba12e2c52500dda0f2a7ede66f91f15fb2f702c1760

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the destination of the transaction, it is a contract. That particular contract has a function whose signature is `multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256[] values)` (see [contract source](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb59fdff77a6175dfa4fe7af4281a52f61611eaa2#code)). By iterating through the input arrays, the function invokes the `transfer` function multiple times. The transaction you linked to invokes the `multisend` function and is thus able to transfer tokens to many wallets at once.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with @lungj. I would add a word of caution.

"Talking" to multiple untrusted contracts in a single transaction is an **anti-pattern**.

From a quick glance at the contract, it appears to be wide open to DoS attack. I wouldn't recommend that pattern unless you are quite sure you understand the attack vector and there is something else mitigating the risk.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Hitchens! I'm interested in hiring someone to implement this for an existing smart contract I have. Could you email me at dgimness@gmail.com if you're available? Sorry, but I can't private message on here.