# ERC standard that allows sending tokens from many origins to one destination in one transaction?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-223

I know that any kind of operation over a token is possible so long as you implement the smart contract that achieves what you desire. For example, [a function `multisend` can be developed that allows sending to many destinations in one transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29378/sending-multiple-transactions-at-once/29385).

But is there any ERC spec out there that defines the opposite? That is, sending a token from many addresses (if you own the private key of all of them, of course), each address containing some amount of that token, to one destination?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ERC20 standard is sufficient to do what you want. Users will have to `approve` your smart contract to move their tokens, and you can define a `receiveMultiple` function in your contract that loops through a parameter that is an array of addresses and amounts to take from them

Comment: mmm, but the approve operation goes into one transaction itself, so this wouldn't allow saving fees which is the ultimate reason I wanted to do everything in one transaction

Comment: alternatively the token can have a `signedTransfer` that takes a signed message to transfer as authorization, but that wouldn't be work for contract that holds the tokens

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your meaning is multi-signature.if so, there is a contract you can have a look.https://etherscan.io/address/0x851b7f3ab81bd8df354f0d7640efcd7288553419#code

Comment: of course I don't mean multisig

Comment: I said many addresses, not many private keys (each address containing some token balance)

Comment: oh, I think many addresses send some token will generate many transactions, so these need many signature, I think it can not be completed by a contract. If you get what you want at last, you can tell me.